# npm install couldnt read dependencies

Tags: npm

I created a package.json for my web application as following :

```
{
    "name":"chat",
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "private":"true",
    "dependencies":{
        "socket.io":"1.3.7",
        "express":"4.13.3"
    }
}
```

And then when I run `npm install` to install the dependencies I get this message :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` file must be corrupted (like some whitespace or BOM problem), try to recreate the file.

You can check if it by running : `node -p "require('./package.json')"`